# String to date conversion in query

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following "timestamp" in the column

```
Mon Aug 10 12:24:46 CDT 2016
```

so to convert into date, i am doing the following.

```
select * from 
(select TO_DATE(SUBSTR(t.timestamp,9,2) || '-' || SUBSTR(t.timestamp,5,3) ||             
'-' || SUBSTR(t.timestamp,27,2), 'DD-MON-YY')  from table t where 
 t.LENGTH(TRIM(t.timestamp)) = 28 as date) where date <= sysdate;
```

The reason for doing that is, "Oracle sysdate" is returning a current date in the following format

```
20-SEP-16
```

So to compare the oracle sysdate, i am using the above approach.

is there any better approach for doing this, i knew this is inefficient using a group of sub-strings inside a select statement and since my "time stamp" value is too long, i am unable to convert to ORACLE date.

I am using oracle 11 as my Database. any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about switching to a native timestamp format and having a computed column in your current format as text?

Comment: Side note: default date format is configurable and not to be relied upon.

Comment: @KamilG. to switch to a native timestamp format, we still have to do some  substring conversions on the time stamp

Comment: @ylnsagar I'm sorry, but I don't understand your problem here. Timestamp is easily truncated into date.

Comment: What data type is the column? Is it a proper "timestamp with time zone" or is it a varchar2 or similar string type? Also, what output do you need... do you just need to compare to the current date/time? Or, actually, it seems you are truncating the time-of-day from the timestamp, is that your requirement? What if the timestamp was at 22:30 and the current time is 14:30? You do realize that "SYSDATE" has a time-of-day component, right?

Comment: @Kamil G. thanks for your reply. you are right timestamp can be easily truncated to date, but in my time stamp, the time zone is specified as CDT. the time zone in my application is from populated by a java script. so oracle is not able to recognize the time zone CDT.

Comment: @mathguy :: the data type of the column is varchar. the output i need is a a proper date that can be compared with sysdate. you already answered the question. the only problem there is my time stamp shows time zone as CDT which is supposed to show as CST. so oracle can't identify the time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept, assuming the so-called "timestamp" is in fact a string. If it is a proper timestamp with time zone (as it **should** be), then it's even simpler, you can compare to a date directly.

Note two things: In my mapping I don't have "CDT" for some reason but I do have the standard time zone, CST. I am probably missing a daylight savings time file which I don't care to hunt down and install. And Aug-10-2016 was a Wednesday; Monday won't work, you can't fool Oracle. Wonder why you didn't bother to use an actual, correct date (including the correct day of the week).

**Edit**: Actually I am not missing any "time zone codes file"; instead, to recognize CDT as a valid time zone, the TZR component in the model below needs to be changed to TZD.

PROOF OF CONCEPT:

```
select 'x' as col1
from   dual
where  to_timestamp_tz('Wed Aug 10 12:24:46 CST 2016', 
                       'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy') <=   sysdate
;



COL1
-----
x

1 row selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. your query work perfectly for time zone CST, but in my time stamp it's mentioned "CDT". so the oracle is complaining "time zone region not found".

Comment: Sorry, I should have researched this sooner. Please change TZR to TZD in the format model and try again. I will add this to my answer as well.

Comment: Great solution. I didn't know of  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ . Add a third parameter to match the language used in the string, e.g. 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'. 'Wed' and 'Aug' are abbreviations that might have no meaning in the session's language setting.

Comment: @mathguy :: thanks for the solution. it worked with TZD. great, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

1. The `as date` is in the wrong place.
2. 'Aug' is a month name abbreviation in a certain language. Specify that language in `to_char` to make sure it works independent of your current setting.
3. Don't only use YY when you have YYYY available.
4. At last there is the time zone 'CDT'. Is it always 'CDT' or can it be something else? If you need to get from one time zone to another, you'd have to convert to timestamp with timezone first, then move to the other timezone, then convert to date.

Here is the query:

```
select * 
from
(
  select 
    cast(from_tz(cast("date" as timestamp), zone) at time zone 'CDT' as date) as "date"
  from 
  (
    select to_date(substr(t.timestamp,9,2) || '-' || 
                   substr(t.timestamp,5,3) || '-' || 
                   substr(t.timestamp,25,4), 
                   'DD-MON-YY', 
                   'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') as "date",
           substr(t.timestamp,21,3) as zone
    from table t 
    where t.length(trim(t.timestamp)) = 28
  ) 
)
where "date" <= sysdate;
```

Despite its name `from_tz` doesn't convert *from* a timezone, but from a timestamp *without* timezone to a timestamp *with* timezone. So we use this to put our timezone information in. `timestamp at time zone 'xyz'` on the other hand moves the timezone to the one specified (the one we interprete our dates to reside in). `cast` is used to get from date to timestamp and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but still you are using substring function your query, is there a way without that substring function

Answer (score -1):

You can use TO_CHAR function to extract date formate
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm

Comment: i saw the link. but the problem in my time stamp is, i have that string "CDT 2016" which cannot be represented by any abbreviation of time.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that,
check TO_TIMESTAMP & TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ instead

Comment: http://psoug.org/snippet/TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ_653.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm